# WinRT Component: C1189: #error: "No Target Architecture"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime

I recently needed to use OutputDebugString() in a WinRT component project, which required this line:

```
 #include <..\um\debugapi.h>
```

However, adding this include produces the error:

> Error 1   error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture" c:\...

To attempt to fix this I opened Configuration Manager and set the platform for the project to x64 (undesirable fix for a WinRT component but I wanted to see if it worked).  Unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue and I'm unable to build.  I'm open to any method for printing debug output to the VS Output window if there's an alternative that alleviates the error.

EDIT: The error occurs in winnt.h line 146 in case this is helpful.

Comment: Are you really using VS 2010, or is that a typo in your tag list?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by adding `#include <windows.h>` in addition to `#include <debugapi.h>`

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by adding the precompiled header include:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <..\um\debugapi.h>
```

Comment: Thanks, but pch.h is already included.  I just tried this with a clean file/new project that has a default pch.h and the same issue occurs.

Comment: @JamesCadd - I assume you have update 3 installed for VS? I'm not sure what else to say. I get the exact error you do if I comment out the include for "pch.h" (error at line 146 in winnt.h).